# Can the xcode simulator be used in place of bluestacks

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode12, bluestacks

I've been following Apples's swift lesson book and learned about the xcode simulator.
I have also been using Bluestacks to emulate an Android phone in order to run games on my mac.
With the update to Big Sur Beta, Bluestacks no longer works (I know the developers of Bluestacks are working on a solution).

In the meantime, I was wondering if it is possible to use the xcode simulator to run a complete iPhone. Currently, it only has a limited version of the operating system that is missing a lot of settings and the appstore. Want I want is to be able to boot the simulator from my physical iPhone's backup, which is stored on my computer. Note: My xcode is Version 12.2 beta 3 (12B5035g).
This way, I could have a duplicate of my physical iPhone on the mac.

I have no idea if this is possible. Knowing how Apple is, it probably isn't, but I thought I'd ask anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It's not possible to run games on a simulator. Better wait for bluestack developer to fix the issue.
P.S: I am also waiting for them to fix the issue :)

Update: Bluestack now supports Big-sur just download the latest version. Note you need to use safari to download the dmg and just install and run :) [Bluestack](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360053434311-How-to-use-BlueStacks-on-MacOS-11-Big-Sur)

Comment: Ok. I figured that was the case. Waiting it is!

Comment: I have updated the answer let me know if the solutions worked :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I will check it in a couple of days when my new internet arrives and see if it works.

Comment: Hope it helps you :)

Comment: It does work. Not the version that was available when you wrote the "update" but the next version after. It doesn't even require any permissions anymore.